# Do Strings inside SLF4j loggers consume heap space

Tags: java, string, performance, heap-memory

My big application contains processing of big code, which includes String literals also.

As a part of code cleanup activity, I am declaring all String Literals as a String final static constant variables.

After which I am expecting some improvement in performance of my application.

I am using SLF4j for logging.

My question is - Strings inside logs also should be declared as final constants?

For e.g. LOGGER.info("My logs");

Does it also consume heap memory space ? Or Should I leave them as is?

Comment: Your String literals like `"My logs"` do not need to be made into static constants *unless it helps with readability or correctness*. They are essentially already similar to static constants

Answer (score 0):

The JVM has a special memory allocation for constant strings: the Java String Pool. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool for details.

In your example, if you have a 100 `LOGGER.info("...")` statements using the same exact string, it will be stored only once in memory.

Also in other places, converting duplicated String literals into final static constants is not necessary for memory usage, but it might make it more maintainable.